# Grey out recyclerview items which the user has clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Working on an app where news get displayed in recyclerview. I want to add a functionality where when the user `clicks` on one of the `recyclerview items` (which opens the news in a new activity) the item gets `greyed out` (or something that indicates that the user has opened said news). My idea was to get the news ID the user clicked on and add it to sharedpreferences file. With that I could create a simple check and grey out news where the ID equals to the one in the `SharedPreferences` file. I feel like that isn't the best way to do it but I can't think of any other way. Any feedback is much appreciated! :)

**Recyclerview**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mainTextBGColor"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: this depends on where you get the news content from

Comment: I get the news content from a database which I have made. News get added from a website into the database and then the app fetches the news. I also had the idea of using another database to store user IDs and then adding a specific user ID to the news which he has read but I don't personally like the idea as much cause that would mean the functionality would not work offline and every time a user opens a new news the app has to add something to a database.

Answer (score 0):

since you can access the backend, consider making an endpoint which you can call when a particular news item gets clicked(pass the news id) and save the news item with the given id as `viewed`. Now when you fetch the news list, pass the `viewed` field also in the api. Now in the android end while you display it in recyclerview, check against this `viewed` field to consider if the item is to be grayed out or not

or you may use other persistent storage methods like `realm` , `sqlite` etc

Comment: Can't exactly understand what you mean, mind giving me an example?

Comment: what is the url that you have created to fetch the news items?

Comment: Currently its localhost. I feel like I explained it a little bad. I need to keep each user seperate. If user A1 has read news 1 and 3 then only those news should be greyed out. I don't want user B1 to see news 1 and 3 greyed on the app. The url gets 10 news at once and turns them into json which I have made a function for in the app to fetch.